# How to handle sprites in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have one image (sprite) that contains two images (selected icon and non selected icon). The width of image is same but its height is double because of second image. How can I get these two images separately from one image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with this piece of code:

```
    private Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(boolean isSelected){
     Bitmap fullImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sprite);
     Bitmap piece = null;
     int height = fullImage.getHeight()/2;
     if(isSelected){
         // show first image
         piece = Bitmap.createBitmap(fullImage, 0, 0, fullImage.getWidth(), height);
     }else{
         // show second image
         piece = Bitmap.createBitmap(fullImage, 0, height, fullImage.getWidth(), height);
     }
     return piece;
    }
```